# images in grid resize when putting images inside anchor tags

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, css-grid

I have a responsive (amount of columns change when device width changes) grid layout. Initially works as I want it to but cannot make images clickable.
For making images clickable, I want to put them inside anchor tags to link to some subdomain. **However, when I do this (surround images in anchor tags, or any other tags for that matter such as div) these images resize/seem to not follow the CSS styles I set for these images anymore**. I don't know why. Please see Codepen and image below. Any input appreciated!

[image: screenshot of issue]
Smaller images on bottom right are the ones with the anchor tags around them

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Maarten-Mtr/pen/BavLRax)** (*note: last two images in the grid are with anchor tags*)

I don't understand why putting `<a>` tags around the images would make my CSS selector `.photos img` not work anymore, since I thought this selector is for all `img` elements inside the div with class 'photos' and the images in the grid are still inside the `.photos` div. Perhaps somehow the anchor elements are overriding (part of) my CSS styles and causing the image to resize in that way? Is this true and if so how can I prevent this resize whilst making the image clickable (surrounded in anchor tags)?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#imageTextGrid {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  /* display: flex; */
}

.photos {
  display: flex;
  /* background-color: #000; */
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.photos img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: .35vw;
  background-color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .photos img {
    width: calc(100%/3);
    height: calc(100%/3);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .photos img {
    width: calc(100%/2);
    height: calc(100%/2);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 50px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .photos img {
    width: calc(100%/1);
    height: calc(100%/1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="imageTextGrid">
  <div class="photos">
    <!-- <img class="thumbnailImg" src="img/about page 1/proj_thumnails/1_apeldoorn.PNG" /> -->
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <a><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only the direct children of the flex container are flex items. So once you wrap a `a` around the images, that becomes the flex item, and Flexbox rules don't apply to the image. So if you want links around those images, you'll need to start from scratch, rethinking your styles.

Comment: @ralph.m thanks for explaining, do you think that using anchor tags with background images instead of image elements wrapped in anchor tags is a good alternative for making the images clickable whilst keeping these elements as first children of the flex container which would keep them acting as flex items?

Comment: No, I would just tweak the CSS to make links wrap around the embedded/inline images. Seem my demos below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the images resize when placed inside of anchor tags is because you have declared the image size to be a percentage, which is a percentage of the parent element's size.

```css
.photos img {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  height: calc(100%/3);
}
```

To resolve this issue, declare `width: 100%` when the images are inside anchors (the selector has higher specificity) and include the anchor in the selector for calculating the image widths.

```css
.photos a img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .photos a,
  .photos img {
    width: calc(100%/3);
    height: calc(100%/3);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#imageTextGrid {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  /* display: flex; */
}

.photos {
  display: flex;
  /* background-color: #000; */
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.photos img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: .35vw;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.photos a img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .photos a,
  .photos img {
    width: calc(100%/3);
    height: calc(100%/3);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .photos a,
  .photos img {
    width: calc(100%/2);
    height: calc(100%/2);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 50px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .photos a,
  .photos img {
    width: calc(100%/1);
    height: calc(100%/1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="imageTextGrid">
  <div class="photos">
    <!-- <img class="thumbnailImg" src="img/about page 1/proj_thumnails/1_apeldoorn.PNG" /> -->
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" />
    <a><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Additionally, the majority of your CSS declarations are unnecessary, including `height` and `calc()`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.photos {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.photos img {
  padding: .35vw;
}

.photos a img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .photos a,
  .photos img {
    width: calc(100%/3);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .photos a,
  .photos img {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 50px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .photos a,
  .photos img {
    width: 100%;
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="imageTextGrid">
  <div class="photos">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <a><img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg"></a>
    <a><img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Furthermore, the CSS can be greatly simplified by using CSS Grid instead of Flexbox

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.photos {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  gap: .35vw;
}

.photos img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageTextGrid">
  <div class="photos">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg">
    <a><img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg"></a>
    <a><img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough to do this with Flexbox or Grid, but Grid is nicer, as it doesn't have stragglers resized at the end.

Here's a quick Grid demo (tweak as needed):

```css
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#imageTextGrid {
    width: 100vw;
}

.photos {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    gap: 10px;
}

.photos a {
  aspect-ratio: 626/ 417;
}

.photos img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageTextGrid">
  <div class="photos">
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a quick Flexbox demo:

```css
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#imageTextGrid {
    width: 100vw;
}

.photos {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
}

.photos a {
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  aspect-ratio: 626/ 417;
}

.photos img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageTextGrid">
  <div class="photos">
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img class="thumbnailImg" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/puppy-that-is-walking-snow_1340-37228.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @ralph.m said in the comments on the question, only the direct children of the flex container are flex items, so once you wrap an anchor element around an image, the anchor becomes the flex item instead of the image.

However, if you apply the style `display: contents` to the anchor element, that element is ‘removed’ from the display hierarchy and its child elements (the image) effectively move up a level in the hierarchy (so the image will become the flex item again).